# Do you do this in every step definition ? "Given that I am logged in"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, bdd

I am new to cucumber.

And for most of the site's functionality, you have to be logged in.

So when writing cucumber, do you write, `given that I am logged in` for every step definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I typically do, yes. For me, it seems clearer when you're reading the tests and seeing the output in the console.

If you don't want the duplication you can use a [Background](http://wiki.github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber/background) to setup stuff that's common to all the scenarios in the file.

Comment: I personally use a Background, but I think it is just a personal preference.